# Sort an array of Vector2 relative to origin clockwise

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, vector, unity-game-engine

I found a piece of code that I've tried using to sort an array of Vector2's in a clockwise order, relative to a specified origin point, but it seems sorta random as to whether it works or not, and it's out of my knowledge to be able to fix it.

I found [this code](http://pastebin.com/1RkaP28U#), from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/877169/vector2-array-sort-clockwise.html) and I'm using that one, but I suspect something is wrong with it and I'm unable to find the issue, so I need help with fixing the code if there's an issue with it.

Here's how I'm using it *(in case I'm doing this part wrong)*:

```
Vector2[] clockwise = new Vector2[] { point1, point2, point3 };
Array.Sort(clockwise, new ClockwiseComparer((point1 + point2 + point3) / 3f));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the origin right, instead of adding all vectors.

Comment: How do I "set it right"? The 3 points are pretty much randomly generated, and I need these 3 ordered in a clockwise fashion. I thought adding up the 3 vectors and dividing by 3 would set the origin to the center. I did some testing, and visualized the center and it looked very obvious that the point I had was the center, so the vectors should've gotten sorted correctly, but they didn't.

Comment: You have to pick up what "point 0" (actually vector zero) is. I.e. on a watch that's 12 o'clock, Which would be a Vector(0,1) (x=0, y=1). Then the vectors can be sorted as the angle from that vector onward.

Comment: @Darek I'm not sure I understand. Could you give an example with some code? My vectors are not always close to (0,0).

Comment: The comparer needs a starting point for the sort. The Comparer gets invoke to compare two vectors when the array is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Without seeing your Vector2 ctor, I have no clue if this will work.

```
Vector2[] clockwise = new Vector2[] { point1, point2, point3 };
clockwise = Array.Sort(clockwise, new ClockwiseComparer( new Vector2(0,1));
```